# Enviar datos a otro componente y luego ir a él

Tags: angular, formularios

uso Angular 14, node js 16. Tengo un formulario con un textbox y un botón, lo que quiero es que al darle al botón, envíe lo que tiene el textbox a otro componente y luego ir a él.

Los componentes padre-hijo funcionan según los ejemplos que he visto, cuando el padre contiene al hijo y el hijo se ve todo el tiempo.

El componente que recibe los datos necesito que solo aparezca cuando recibe algo para buscar.

Componente menú:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <input type="text" formControlName="video" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
</form> 
    

onSubmit() {
        this.submitted = true; 
        console.log("menu component", this.myForm.value);   
        --enviar datos al otro componente
       --hacer que el otro componente se vea
}
```

Al poner esto en el componente padre

```
<app-hero-child
      *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
      [hero]="hero"
      [master]="master">
    </app-hero-child>
```

se ve el componente hijo dentro del padre... la idea es ir al componente hijo.

¿Se puede hacer de esta forma? ¿como se haría? o ¿hay que hacerlo de otra forma?

Answer (score 0):

Si todo está funcionando como dices, puedes utilizar una bandera *(estado boolean)* para determinar si mostrar o no el componente hijo.

En tu componente padre defines la variable:

```
public showChild: boolean = false;
```

Y lo envías a través de la función que ya tienes:

```
onSubmit() {
  this.submitted = true;
  console.log("menu component", this.myForm.value);
  //enviar datos al otro componente
  //hacer que el otro componente se vea
  this.showChild = true;
}
```

y dentro de la interpolación.

```
<app-hero-child
  *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
    [(visible)]="showChild"
    [hero]="hero"
    [master]="master"
></app-hero-child>
```

Entonces, lo recuperas en el hijo con un decorador.

```
@Input() visible: boolean;
```

Y lo utilizas para mostrar o no tu componente hijo.

```
*ngIf="visible"
```